# Taking multiplicities into account when counting the elements of a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Say we have a list

`l = {4x,3y,z}`

When we do

`Count[l,x]`

we get, as expected

> 0

Is there a function, call it F, that takes multiplicities into account, so for example for `l`

`F@l`

> {4,3,1}

or equivalently a function that extracts multiplicities of each element in a list?

Comment: Your example is probably too simplistic to really represent what you want. For example, `F = Coefficient[#, {x, y, z}] &` works just fine. Is this what you want? Is there a more complex example where this does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`FactorTermsList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorTermsList):

```
First @* FactorTermsList /@ {4 x, 3 y, z}
```

> {4, 3, 1}